# how do i increase Heap Memory Size Programatically

Tags: java, heap-memory

i  have sample code for increase Heap Memory.But it is not increasing Memory.
sample Code :

```
         int mb=1024*1024;
        long rt=Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();


        int heapsize=(int) (rt/mb);
        System.out.println("Heap Size : " +heapsize);
         String[] cmd = {"cmd.exe", "/c", "cd/C C:\\Users\\xxxxxx\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\MultiThreadSample\\src\\multithreadsample && java -Xms61m -Xmx128m"};
        Process exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        exec.destroy();
```

SpawnAndChangeHeap is the class name.Can You Please Suggest Me?

Comment: I would not expect there is any way to do this.

Comment: You cannot increase the heap memory of an already running application.

Comment: suppose if i set in Environment Variable,will it work or not?...@SvetlinZarev

Comment: Here is not running Application.we have to stop the app and again start the aplication,while starting it has to show refresh Memory....@LouisWasserman ..

Comment: It's really unclear. Your command is probably wrong - it doesn't run any class. Which class are you trying to run, and does it have any connection with the current class, or is the current class just a controlling object? And why are you destroying the process you just created?

Comment: so how can i increase Heap Memory?@RealSkeptic

Comment: if i not destroy the process,it will be in running Application and in running application we can not increase Heap Memory..@RealSkeptic

Comment: if i run this application 2nd time it has to show  Heap Size : 128..Right?why because i am destroying process 1st time...means Refesh Memory will show..This Scenario is Right or wrong ,,,dnt know.....@RealSkeptic

Answer (score 0):

java heap allocation are continuous and happens at JVM initialization. Programmatically heap size cannot be extended or modified until Xmx or Xms changed with JVM restart.